# Hash files are different after taking same screen shot with Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm trying to learn about automated tests, using Selenium. I'm working alone, and so only have the docs, Google and then you guys.

Using Selenium in VS-2105, I save a screen shot of my website as an image to a file location, and then stop debugging at that point. This file then becomes the 'expected' result.

I then comment that line out, run it again, taking a screen shot but saving to a different location. The files, although of the same size, have different hash values.

To my eyes they are identical.

Is there something wrong with my approach?

This is the code which I run to create my 'master'

```
        _webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

        var accept = _webDriver.SwitchTo().Alert();
        accept.Accept();

        IWebElement menu = _webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("link"));

        menu.Click();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

        var screenshot = _webDriver.GetScreenshot();

        var fileName = "expandMenuInPlan.png";
        var origFile = _testImagesPersistentPath + fileName;
        screenshot.SaveAsFile(origFile, OpenQA.Selenium.ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
```

And this is the code I use to compare

```
        _webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

        var accept = _webDriver.SwitchTo().Alert();
        accept.Accept();

        IWebElement menu = _webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("link"));

        menu.Click();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

        var screenshot = _webDriver.GetScreenshot();

        var fileName = "expandMenuInPlan.png";
        var origFile = _testImagesPersistentPath + fileName;
        //screenshot.SaveAsFile(origFile, OpenQA.Selenium.ScreenshotImageFormat.Png); COMMENTED OUT

//The above is identical

        var newFile = _testImagesTempForTestRunPath + fileName;
        screenshot.SaveAsFile(newFile, OpenQA.Selenium.ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);

        string hashOrig = GetBytes(origFile);
        string hashNew = GetBytes(newFile);

        if (hashOrig != hashNew)
        {
            SaveFailedImage(origFile, newFile, fileName);
        }
```

And the GetBytes method

```
    private string GetBytes(string file)
    {
        using (SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            var img = new Bitmap(file);
            ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
            var bytes = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
            return Convert.ToBase64String(sha1.ComputeHash(bytes));
        }
    }
```

Is using screenshots in this manner just not reliable or is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: I don't think a screenshot will ever match another down to every pixel. Comparing images is done by using a threshold of variance because you never get exact matches.

Answer (score 0):

Hashing a image file and comparing is never the right approach. Even a single pixel off will change the hash. So you don't want to to make your tests brittle

You can use the C# method `ImageComparer.Compare Method (Image, Image, ColorDifference, Image)`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/hh191601.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Or you can use external tools like https://applitools.com/ which allow you to do compare images which are smart in nature

PS: I have no association with applitools and it is just one example, there might be other services available as well.

Comment: If you compare two images with one pixel different, it will still fail whether you hash it or not. So why is this approach any different?

Comment: @JeffC, because the third parameter is `ColorDifference argbTolerance`, which allows to have tolerance in image comparison

Comment: I know, but you didn't mention anything about that parameter or how to use it. And saying that anything is "never" the right approach is... never a good approach.